# Check for response every 100ms

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, response, tcpclient

I made this TCP client and it is working but when it checks for incoming stream it pauses app...(Source code - https://app.box.com/s/7ly47ukztlo5eta3wqbk)
Here is that part :

```
        void check()
        {
            if (tcpclnt.Connected == true)
            {
                NetworkStream stm2 = tcpclnt.GetStream();
                if (stm2.CanRead)
                {
                    // Reads NetworkStream into a byte buffer. 
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpclnt.ReceiveBufferSize];

                    // Read can return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead.  
                    // This method blocks until at least one byte is read.
                    stm2.Read(bytes, 0, (int)tcpclnt.ReceiveBufferSize);

                    // Returns the data received from the host to the console. 
                    string returndata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

                    log("SERVER: " + Environment.NewLine + returndata + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            check();
        }
```

Comment: check out [backgroundworker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)

Comment: The terminology for this is "blocking" vs "non-blocking" sockets; a "blocking" socket pauses until data is available, a "non-blocking" socket will return 0 if no bytes are presently available. You can do this on the UI thread, but you need to use a "non-blocking" socket.

Comment: The Read() call will block until data is received.  Blocking your UI thread as well and making it go catatonic.  Which is why there's a NetworkStream.BeginRead() method, it doesn't block.  And doesn't need a Timer.  Check the MSDN article to get that kind of code correct.

Comment: You are ignoring the return value from `stm2.Read`. That's a bug. I'm confused because in your comment you're even referring to that possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `check()` 'pauses' the app because its job is currently executed in the UI thread.

If you don't want that your method freezes the UI, you should schedule the execution of the method in a background thread, different from your UI thread.

You can do that using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) thread. An example, as suggested by @qujck, is [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker).